# Oracle APEX - Setting Null Display Value for POPUP LOVs

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

I have a few select list boxes on my page and when nothing is selected, I want the value to be shown as `Select a Value`. So I set `Null Display Value` property to `Select a Value`. That works fine for select lists that are using either a shared list or a SQL query as its source, but not for those that use Popup LOV as its source. How can I set null display value for Popup LOVs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put "Select a Value" into the **Value Placeholder** Popup LOV item's property.